# My script to delete emails seems to be running but it does nothing

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, gmail

I made a script to delete emails labelled "Send Mail Script".
It runs without error but it doesn't delete the emails labelled "Send Mail Script"

Here's the script:

```
function DeleteEmail() {
  var threads = GmailApp.search('label:Send Email Script');

  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {

    var thread = threads[i],
        messages = thread.getMessages();


    thread.moveToTrash(messages);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the space in label names with dashes. See updated code:

```
function DeleteEmail() {
  var threads = GmailApp.search('label:Send-Email-Script');    
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
     threads[i].moveToTrash();
  }
}
```